# ANOVA in R Salaries

Tags: r, anova

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to run an ANOVA on salaries from 5 NBA Teams. I was trying to change salary to a factor but I suspect I missed a step. I greatly appreciate a response. Please see below.

```
> read.csv("~/DATA630/ANOVANBATeams.csv")
    Pistons    Wizards  Cavaliers   Clippers    Thunder
1 7,000,000 16,957,900 18,000,000 21,468,695 17,832,627
2 3,650,000  5,497,625 21,108,899  6,938,750  4,663,129
3   2772440  4,440,000  5,982,375 10,188,750  2,757,500
4 5,479,933  2,123,733  4,525,000  1,448,490  2,184,960
5 1,208,325  1,448,490    903,456    613,478    966,800

> > read.csv("~/DATA630/ANOVANBATeams.csv", header = TRUE)
Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
> salary <- read.csv("~/DATA630/ANOVANBATeams.csv", header = TRUE)
> salary$Team = as.factor(salary$Team)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Team", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 5
```

Comment: If you look at the output from `read.csv()`, your data frame doesn't have a column called `Team`. That's why it's giving you an error.

Comment: Also you say that you're trying to turn salary into a factor but I assume you meant team, which is what you're doing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want your data in a long format with the team name as a factor. Try this:

```
salary <- read.csv("~/DATA630/ANOVANBATeams.csv", header=T)

Teams <- colnames(salary)

salary2 <- reshape(salary, direction="long", varying=list(Teams), ids=Teams)
colnames(salary2)[2:3] <- c("Salary", "Team")
```

The commas in the salaries keep R from properly converting them to numbers, so we can remove them with `gsub()`.

```
salary2$Salary <- as.numeric(gsub(",", "", salary2$Salary)))
salary2$Team <- as.factor(salary2$Team)
```

Do your analysis of variance.

```
aov(Salary ~ Team, data=salary2)
```

Comment: I received a message that says my ANOVA might be unbalanced. Is this something that I should be concerned about? I greatly appreciate your assistance. Please see log below: Call:
   aov(formula = Salary ~ Team, data = salary2)

Terms:
                        Team    Residuals
Sum of Squares  7.044869e+14 3.779949e+14
Deg. of Freedom            4           20

Residual standard error: 4347384
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

Comment: That's more of a statistics question and is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow. I recommend reading about conducting [one-way ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance). Check the assumptions, use a nonparametric test if necessary.

Comment: I attempted to set up a boxplot but didn't get what I was looking for. It looks like the graph gave me plots for each salary instead of each team name. Please help

boxplot(Salary~Team, data=salary2, xlab= "NBA Team", ylab= "Salary (dollars)")   Please see the image  http://127.0.0.1:35095/graphics/plot_zoom_png?width=942&height=704